# OAuth Dialog Redirect URL options when Facebook url is blocked

Tags: url, facebook-authentication, blocked

We are creating an app for a private school. The school's technical team has blocked students from accessing Facebook. For our app, we must authenticate the students within the school. Are there alternate URLs that can be used to access OAuth Dialog to allow our app to authenticate users on the school's computer even though the primary Facebook URL is blocked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sign in with Facebook oauth, without full facebook.com access](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8995467/sign-in-with-facebook-oauth-without-full-facebook-com-access)